# Capturing and preserving URI on redirect on Apache php Server without 404 header

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Capturing and preserving URI on redirect on Apache php Server without 404 header

I'm building a news website/blog. I want to format the URL in a specific way. Like the following:

http://example.com/news/1234/title_of_article/

I don't want the hassle and mess of creating a directory structure for every article. I've set my .htaccess file to redirect to a main file with

ErrorDocument 404 /main_file.php

My main file then uses $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] to find out what page was requested, and then build the the page.

It all works well. The only problem, I believe the .htaccess redirect sends a 404 header to the client. I've tried to counteract this with a follow up 200 header in the main file, but I don't think it works. W3C Validator detects the 404 still and search engines don't seem to index the pages.

How can I keep the format of the URL without sending a 404 error to the browser? Is there an easy alternative without making dozens of folders?

Comment: 1.) sending 2 http status headers never makes sense. 2.) the ".htaccess redirect" sends no http header. So what is the real problem?

Comment: I'd say your basic strategy to rewrite the 404 error document is wrong. You chose the wrong approach. Don't wait until the server hits the 404 document, rewrite the original request instead. Rewrite it to you main_file.php and you are fine.

Comment: The address http://example.com/news/1234/title_of_article/ is not a file on the server. When that address is called upon, htaccess does "ErrorDocument 404 main_file.php". Main file then creates the page requested. As far as the user is concerned, "title of article" exists. However if I put that address into WC3 validator, it detects an error 404. If the htaccess didn't generate it, where did it come from? I only added this "second header" to counteract the phantom 404. I've now found that I can send a header 301 to stop the 404, but it's not ideal. I'd prefer 200.

Comment: I fully understood your stategy, still this is the wrong strategy. Actually in most of todays pages or systems on the internet this is not the case. Instead rewrite the request _before_ it hits the error 404, so right at the beginning. You pick the parameters you need from the incoming request and rewrite the request to whatever you like. Note: you rewrite the _incoming_ request. That way the system never looks for a physical file, so it never throws an error 404 but calls your script instead handing over the parameters just as you do now. This is the normal strategy for rewriting requests.

Comment: I had misunderstood you. I did not realise what you meant by rewrite. I am by no means an expert at Apache commands. My knowledge is limited to .htaccess and ErrorDocument commands.

Comment: You are already actually doing a rewrite the way you have your script called. All I suggest is: rewrite the original requests, not the final request to the error document. It does not amtter if you do that rewriting in the central server configuration (preferred) or in `.htaccess`style files (slow and error prone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple internal redirect to redirect any file or folder that does not exist to your `main_file.php` instead of using the `ErrorDocument` for doing it:

```
# if folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if file does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# redirect anything to
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main_file.php/$1 [L]
```

And handle it using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or you can further customize it to handle it as parameters like this:

```
# if folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if file does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# redirect anything to
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ main_file.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

The above would internally redirect:

```
http://example.com/news/1234/title_of_article/
```

To:

```
http://example.com/main_file.php?category=news&id=1234&title=title_of_article
```

However the browser URL would remain:

```
http://example.com/news/1234/title_of_article/
```

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I want to do. I presume this is all entered into the .htaccess file. I commented out my ErrorDocument, and placed your first example into the htaccess. So far, I've not seen it spring into action. I'm reviewing the Apache Documentation now: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: @The_Stewart and what happens when u place it in, give me a detailed information so I can tell you what may be wrong and how to fix.

Comment: I get the generic Apache 404 page. You know the one: Not Found, The requested URL /news/1234/ was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." It seems as if it doesn't recognise the RewriteCond being met.

Comment: @The_Stewart that means main_file.php does not exist. Can you tell me where the file is, for example `http://example.com/file.php?id=1234` if this is where the file is and leads you to the topic then that's where we need to rewrite it to.

Comment: Originally I tried your code as is, but now I've tried changing the locations with no luck too. At present, main_file and htaccess are in the same directory at the server's top level. "ErrorDocument 404 /main_file.php" finds the file. So I changed "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main_file.php/$1 [L]" to "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main_file.php/$1 [L]". It has to be an oversight.

Comment: @The_Stewart sorry on the late response was away, then I believe your problem is that you have something like WordPress installed and by default WordPress sends everything to the index.php file and handles 404 by itself I have tried both of the above rules and they work as expected on my server with main_file.php on the root folder.

Comment: Don't worry about any delay. I'm grateful for any help. Well, if you say that the commands should work, I'll have to get hold of my hosting company. While I don't see anything enabled on the account, I wouldn't be surprised if something is interfering. I'll just mark this as solved in the meantime.

Comment: @The_Stewart could you update your question with your exact .htaccess you have just replace any sensitive data and I will try the rules with your rules and see if anything comes up, also are you using WordPress or making your own PHP CMS and if so are u using any framework like codeigniter or from scratch?

Comment: Everything I do is from scratch. I learn and do it the hard way. My host has loads of documentation. I've managed to get it going using their docs: Options +FollowSymlinks
**RewriteEngine On**
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /logicgate.php [L]

Comment: @The_Stewart then ask them if mod_rewrite is enabled and available on your account, check if there is no others .htaccess in other directories and make sure the .htaccess you're using is placed on the root folder of your domain. The root folder usually is called public_html but may vary from hosting company to hosting company

Comment: It's all good from here. As long as I specify "RewriteEngine On" in the htaccess, the commands work. The file is happily sitting in my root folder and is the only one. Thanks for all the help.